# Ubuntu is not serving Static files from Django project. Getting Permission issue

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

[Updated status]: It has been resolved by Updating the permission of root folder. update the user in nginx.conf with user can be option but I have not tried this one.

===== Actual Question============

I have a django project deployed on Ubuntu 23.04 and using nginx and gunicorn to serve the website. Static setting is defined as follows:

```
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        STATIC_DIR,
    ]
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

We have Debug = False in Production.

Gunicorn service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=opinionsdeal.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=panelviewpoint
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/panelviewpoint/opinionsdealnew
ExecStart=/home/panelviewpoint/opinionsdealnew/venv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/opinionsdeal.sock \
          opinions_deal.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

nginx file

```
server {
    server_name opinionsdeal.com www.opinionsdeal.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/panelviewpoint/opinionsdealnew;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/opinionsdeal.sock;
    }
}
```

SSL lines have been removed from nginx file in this code only but it is already there in server. I am using Django 4.2 and python 3.11

We are seeing that website HTML pages are being served but static files like js, css and images are not being served.

I have deployed similar projects in past on ubuntu 20 and worked well but this time it is not working. I have given permission for static folder to all users.

Please suggest if there is any solution.

Comment: Please clarify what Permission issue you're having.

Comment: @ewokx: static files are showing 403 forbidden in browser.

Comment: I have updated permission of /home/panelviewpoint/ folder to everyone and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you edit the nginx configuration `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

And change the user to your Ubuntu user.

`user panelviewpoint;`

Comment: nope. Will try this next time. Now I have updated permission of /home/panelviewpoint/ folder to everyone and it worked.

Thanks for suggestion.